# fwrite печатает мусор в конец файла

Tags: c++, c

Пытаюсь заставить работать следующий код:

```
if (FILE *fp_in = fopen("filename", "rb"))
{
    if (FILE *fp_out = fopen("filename.1", "wb"))
    {
        unsigned char buff[1024] = {0};
        while (size_t len = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp_in))
        {
            unsigned int outLen = 0;  // out param - bytes in сiphertext
            unsigned char *out = foo(buff, len, key, outLen);
            fwrite(out, 1, sizeof(buff), fp_out);
        }
        fclose(fp_out);
    }
    fclose(fp_in);
}
// Обратный процес
if (FILE *fp_in = fopen("filename.1", "rb"))
{
    if (FILE *fp_out = fopen("filename.2", "wb"))
    {
        unsigned char buff[1024] = {0};
        while (size_t len = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp_in))
        { 
            unsigned char *out = bar(buff, len, key);
            printf("%s\n", out);
            fwrite(out, 1, sizeof(buff), fp_out);
        }
        fclose(fp_out);
    }
    fclose(fp_in);
}
```

Файл filename содержит несколько раз повторяющееся слово hello.
Далее я читаю содержимое этого файла, обрабатываю и записываю в файл filename1.

Затем произвожу обратный процес. Читаю из filename1 и пишу в filename2.
Но я столкнулся с трудностями. В файл filename2 записываются слова hello (в нужном количестве) и затем идет много непонятного мусора (Например �}�D���\��>[��[D����9Ѕ�"K�Ic�)

Но когда я вывожу обработанную информацию (printf строка 26) то все хорошо. Но вот при записи возникает вышеописанная проблема.

P.S. Файлы не обязательно текстовые. Полагается что хранятся бинарные данные

Comment: скорее всего вы напутали с длинами: записываете в файлы больше чем нужно. в строках `fwrite(out, 1, sizeof(buff), fp_out);` укажите конкретные размеры вместо `sizeof(buff)`: `outLen` в первом случае и `len` во втором

Comment: Укажите метку одного языка. Так как нет [mre], сложно сказать какого именно, но скорее цэ++, если это не какое-то расширение компилятора

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(buf)` тут эквивалентно 1024, а `fread` мог считать меньше. Для этого и нужно возвращаемое значение числа считанных байт, его следует передавать `fwrite`. Однако не всегда следует тихо сравнивать его с нулем. Нужно сравнивать заданный и полученный размер, и проверять состояние ошибки. Несоответсвие может означать достижение конца файла или ошибку чтения, или недозаполненный буфер. Чтение может происходить из буферизованного потока, и возврат нуля означает, что буфер пуст, а не то, что достигнут конец файла.

Comment: man fread перечитайте внимательно и не фантазируйте о пустом буфере. Ноль возвращается при EOF или ошибке. Для выяснения что именно (eof likely) надо вызывать feof или ferror

Comment: @avp perror. ferror  только скажет, что ошибка имеет место быть. И ман описывает только гарантированное POSIX поведение, некоторые функии ОС могут его поменять. Опустошение является видом ошибки, иногда  ошибка возникает из-за отсутсвия или превышение допустимого размера буфера.. или программист установил размер буфера в ноль, что затсавляет fread вести себя как худшая версия  read

Comment: Какая ОС нам не сказали, в Windows диагностика другая

Comment: Для того чтобы отличить eof от ошибки нужно в случае, когда fread возвращает 0 вызвать или feof или ferror (без разницы). Не нулевое возвращаемое значение это всегда OK. Размер буфера никакого отношения к возврату 0 не имеет.

Comment: Били ситуации: 0 может вернутся запрос слишком большого объема (например. 100 Мб, все зависит от платформы, программист пытался вычислять объем буфера на основе доступной пмяти и  и размера файла) тоже вернет ноль, состяние ошибки ничего  не давала (кроме то что это ошибка) Нужно было проверять установки системы. динамическое уменьшение буфера позволяло продожать чтение )

Comment: не надо программируя неизвестно на чем, переносить этот опыт на нормальные системы

Comment: @avp ну , я соглашусь что Windows CE, WindRiver и Linux не являются нормальными. Но  у разработчиков видимо были причины. Вообще осей , отрекающих отклонения от POSIX очень мало и они специфичны, вроде AIX или LynxOS

Comment: Для Linux пруф можете привести?

Comment: @avp Было достаточно сложно, общение двух приложений через файл в памяти на VESA32 системе. Но вот использование setvbuf для отключения буферизации там почему-то было необходимо, и это можно сымитировать на файле? https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf .

Comment: `setvbuf(file, 0, _IONBF, 0)` для файла? Конечно, можно